# Append rows between rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in the following structure, there are rows that i would like to append to the table dynamically.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Work</td>
            <td>Award</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td><input class="w_name" type='text'/></td>
           <td><input class="other" type='text'/></td>

        </tr>
            <tr>
             <td><input class="w_name" readonly/></td>
            <td><input class="other" type='text'/></td>

        </tr>
            <tr>
           <td><input class="w_name" type='text'/></td>
            <td><input class="other" type='text'/></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and i have this jquery that does the appending

```
$('.btn-add').click(function() {
    var index = $('tr', $(this).closest("tbody")).index(this);
    alert(index);
    var tbody = $('tbody');
    var i = $('tbody tr').size() + 1;            
    tablerow="<tr><td><input class=\"w_name\" type='text'/></td> <td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/></td><td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/></td> <td><input class=\"other\"type='text'/></td><td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/></td><td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/><a href=\"#\" id=\"remScnt\">Remove</a></td><tr>";
     tbody.append(tablerow);
     i++;
     return false;

});
```

I want to append rows between the first tr and the last two trs  in the tbody. Suggestions!

Comment: Maybe use insertBefore() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

Comment: use the [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) jquery functions to append elements after or before elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tableidhere > tbody > tr:first-child').after(tablerow)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H6jH9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way -

```
var newRow = "<tr><td><input class=\"w_name\" type='text'/></td> <td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/></td><td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/></td> <td><input class=\"other\"type='text'/></td><td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/></td><td><input class=\"other\" type='text'/><a href=\"#\" id=\"remScnt\">Remove</a></td><tr>";
$('.add').click(function() {
    $(newRow).insertAfter($('tbody tr:first-child'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yA4CV/